# Prevent Component/PureComponent with styled-components from re-rendering all items after state change

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-dom

After adding styled-components to this example, we've noticed that our list component updates everything when only one item in state is modified.

The list rendering highlights (from React dev-tools) are excessive when adding/removing a single entry. One item is removed/added, then all items get highlighted.

[image]

### code samples

- github: https://github.com/chancesmith/reactjs-optimize-list-updates/tree/master/src
- codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wn45qw44z5

Here is an example of the right list component (CategorizedList.js)

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Item = styled.li`
  color: #444;
`;

class CategorizedList extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.categories.map(category => (
          <ul>
            <li key={this.props.catStrings[category]}>
              {this.props.catStrings[category]}
            </li>
            <ul>
              {this.props.items.map((item, index) =>
                item.category === category ? (
                  <div key={item.label + index}>
                    <Item>{item.label}</Item>
                  </div>
                ) : null
              )}
            </ul>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Preference

I'd prefer to use PureComponent so that `shouldComponentUpdate()` [gets handled automatically](https://codeburst.io/when-to-use-component-or-purecomponent-a60cfad01a81).

### Question

How can we make sure only the modified objects in `items` state are re-rendered?

Comment: according to your link `doing a check on their props and state is lightning fast compared to the cost of re-rendering each one` What kind of performance hit do you expect to take in that list to where you need to take this approach?

Answer (score 1):

If the data changes , the view will re-render. It shouldn't be an expensive process since it happens once on add/remove action. If you find performance issues it might be caused from something else.

In general this would be the way you can have some control on pure-components re-render:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo